# SSRS report - export to excel date time filteration

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdl

Populating an SSRS report from dyanmic dataset i.e. number column and order of columns may vary based on condition, and this report on trying to export to excel. But in exporting date column filtration not working. Finds the reason is I bind the column in string format.

Sample data format to understand. Here the columns & order of columns may vary as per condition.

[image]

And I am converting this to below format and passing to SSRS as dataset.

[image]

And populating report by grouping with ROW_NO & COL

Then I tried to convert DOB column to date time.

For converting DOB to date format changed return type of DOB from sql query as datetime, converted column value to date time using `CDate()` in SSRS and formatted in own format (dd-mmm-yyyy).

Below expression used for converting to date time:

```
IIF((Fields!COL.Value="DOB") ,CDate(Fields!VALUE.Value),(Fields!VALUE.Value))
```

But showing #Error for columns data type other than date time:

[image]

Comment: You have an expression that can return two different datatypes.  Each field (whether from the datasaource or from a calculation) has one datatype and your expression can return either a Date or anything but a date.

Comment: If you run the report in Visual Studio, it will give you the details of the error message. This will help troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your detail textbox in the **DOB** column. And use the following expression:

```
=Format(CDate(Fields!DOBValue.Value), "dd-MM-yyyy")
```

This way the date in your **DOB** column will show `23-01-2018`

Note: The expression just works if in the `Fields!DOBValue.Value` field are just dates. If there is a `N/A` it will throw an error. Then you have to clear the `N/A` first.

And if you want to export it to Excel you need to set the language in your report properties (use your region) and go to your textbox where you wrote in the above expression under **Textbox properties > Number** chose **Date** format.

**UPDATE**

Based on your updated question I think I found the error. The problem is your writing of the month names combined with the report language. My report language is set to `DE`. For me the following works:

```
=CDate("15-Mai-94") 'Result 05.05.1994
```

But this dosent work:

```
=CDate("15-May-94") 'Result =Error
```

The second one works, when I set the report language to `EN` but then the first one throws an error

Comment: can't able specify DOB column in data set. As it is a dynamic report, I am getting the values in Key - Value format. I have updated my question with dataset format for more understanding. Please advise

Comment: I think have little change in ur understanding from real issue. In my case date column showing correctly, but other columns with data type other than date showing #Error. Reason finding is from expression - IIF((Fields!COL.Value="DOB") ,CDate(Fields!VALUE.Value),(Fields!VALUE.Value)) - its returning date type value in true condition & string type value in false condition. Please advise

Comment: But your expression should be right. Try `=IIF(Fields!COL.Value = "DOB", Format(CDate(Fields!VALUE.Value), "dd-MM-yyyy"), Fields!VALUE.Value)`. If this is not working its not the fault of the expression, thus the cause of the error should the reason I mentioned above.

Comment: I done same, but if I formatted date to string 'dd-MM-yyyy' format in exporting to excel date field filtration not working i.e. it is filtering as string not as date.

Comment: This doesnt work I think,iIf you have string and a date in one field. Even when you filter the strings away it wont never be in a Excel export a date format.